# pass query string values in string array

Tags: java, jsp

I am getting a problem while passing query string values in String Array.
The statements are as following.

```
words[0]=request.getParameter("word1");
words[1]=request.getParameter("word2");
```

The above statements gives me an exception and giving value 0.
Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: What exception ? Share the error stack trace.

Comment: Please also post the line in your code where you declare `words`

Comment: @PeterRader Did you read [`ServletRequest` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) carefully enough?

Comment: @skuntsel No. You are right.

Comment: show us exact code where you are getting exception... and what exception?  is it inside jsp? or inside Java class.

Answer (score 3):

Possible solutions/causes:

1. Make sure your **array is initialized**: `String[] words = new String[2]`.
2. Make sure you have your **`input` element inside `form`** that is submitted.